# What rules govern in absence of robots.txt?

Tags: web-crawler

Should a search engine not crawl a website that does not host a robots.txt?

Edit 1:
What if even the robots meta tag is absent? I am trying to determine the legalities involved here. Thats it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A search engine will crawl all publicly accesible pages on a site without a robots.txt file.

Comment: I think you should say may instead of will

Comment: @David you're right, my bad.
It also depends on the `<meta name="robots" content=".....">` tags in the individual pages

Comment: What if even the robots meta tag is absent? I am trying to determine the legalities involved here. Thats it.

Comment: @pranav no, what I mean is the the crawler may decide to skip parts of the site for other reasons

Comment: @David, please enumerate the reasons :)

Comment: crawler may decide the site is not interesting and ignore it. Nothing says it **will** crawl every page

Comment: @David, crawlers are that smart?

Comment: @Pranav Too right they are. The entire internet is huge. If they crawled everything in site indiscriminately then they'd not get things done. Plus, not all crawlers have the resources of Google or MS.

Comment: @David thanks for the info, I didn't know that (crawlers crawl selectively) :)